# User based content posting using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a Codeigniter project at the moment. So far I have the user registration and login system done. But I can't seem to grasp the logic of how each individual user would post content (for example: post a product).

I have the product upload system in place as well (connected to a database) that loads right after you login into your account. But how do I connect it with the user that is currently logged in?

If posting some of the code is necessary to answer this question I'll do that.

It would be great if someone could explain the logic behind doing this.

Model for Login:

```
public function login(){

    $this->db->where('user_handle', $this->input->post('full_name'));
    $this->db->where('user_pass', sha1($this->input->post('password')));

    $query = $this->db->get('reg_users');

    if($query->num_rows() == 1){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Model for Product entry:

```
public function productupload($data){
    $this->db->insert('product_info', $data);
}
```

Controller for Product entry:

```
public function uploadBook(){

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_name', 'Product Name', 'required|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_details', 'Product Details', 'required|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('contact', 'Contact', 'required|trim|xss_clean|numeric|integer');

    $data = array(
            'product_name'=> $this->input->post('product_name'),
            'product_details'=> $this->input->post('product_details'),
            'contact'=> $this->input->post('contact')
        );

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){
        $this->model_productentry->productupload($data);
    } else{
        $this->load->view('uploads/view_upload');
    }
}
```

As you can see in the Controller and the Model for product entry there is no mention of which user the upload should be assigned to. This is what I'm having trouble figuring out.

Comment: Can you please post some example code ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))?  Include what you've already tried and where exactly you're stuck. See more info at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't take it personally, but have you considered maybe you are not ready for an e-commerce project yet?

If this project is for some one else, they have obviously trusted your coding skills and you are responsible for that trust, security for an e-commerce project is very important.

1. Based on your question, you probably don't know about sessions yet? and your `login` function just checks if a user exist (does not log them in)
2. You save user passwords with `sha1($this->input->post('password'))` in an **e-commerce** project... that is unacceptable (do some research about how to store a password securely if you don't want to use an authentication library)
3. Its not just about PHP side, for database performance you need to make some optimizations on that side too

So maybe just practice and read (about PHP Security, Sessions, Database Management etc...) for another 1-2 months before starting this?

> I see very good things in your code too, you always use CodeIgniter functions, such as $this->db->insert() which escapes all queries and is safe, it means you have read User Guide correctly and completely
>
> You also validate all user inputs before doing anything, that's very nice too

But if this is a personal project and you have to do it now, first use a CodeIgniter `Authentication` library, for example [Ion Auth](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/) or [Tank Auth](http://konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/) etc...

These libraries provide secure way for signup / login / password reset / remember me, etc...

Then, when user is logged in using the auth libraries, in your model you can do this:

```
public function productupload(){

    // Get User ID from session if it exists (session is set by auth library)
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

    if ($user_id === FALSE)
    {
        // Set flash data error that user should be logged in
        redirect('login'); // redirect to login page
        // Note that CodeIgniter redirect() function does exit() automatically, if you use PHP redirect you should exit manually right after that!, so always use CodeIgniter functions, but also know the reasons.
    }

    $data = array(
        // Added user_id to $data, so you know which user has inserted this (also add this column in database)
        'user_id'=> $user_id,
        'product_name'=> $this->input->post('product_name'),
        'product_details'=> $this->input->post('product_details'),
        'contact'=> $this->input->post('contact')   
    );

    $query = $this->db->insert('product_info', $data);

    if ($query !== FALSE && $this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
    {
        // Flash data to tell user process was valid
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Yeay, Success...');
        // Always redirect after processing a form
        redirect('controller_name');
    }

    // Maybe set error message?
    // If query failed or not inserted return false
    return FALSE;
}
```

You might also want to check in your model if the User ID from session is allowed to upload or have limits, or maybe if each product should be entered once, check if it already exists with query or database UNIQUE KEY to avoid duplications.

Also as this is an e-commerce project, you should probably change CodeIgniter configs too, for example

```
$config['encryption_key'] = '32_CHARACTER_ENCRYPTION_KEY' // Get a CodeIgniter Encryption Key from http://randomkeygen.com if you don't know how to set it

$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE; // If you enable this, you need to create a table in database (default table name is ci_session)

$config['sess_match_ip']        = TRUE;

$config['cookie_secure']    = TRUE;

$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE; // So you won't forget to filter something

$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE; // protect forms against csrf
```

I suggest changing all cookie and token names in config too.

`This was just a suggestion (and my personal idea) to let you know you have to make some changes and additional checks for such project, many additional checks/protections might be required depending on the project requirements`

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed response. I probably should've mentioned it in the original post that this is strictly a personal project I'm doing as a way to learn.

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty You're welcome, just note that i was referencing to CodeIgniter 2.2 as i haven't changed to 3 yet (i'm waiting for 3.0.1 or possibly 3.0.2 bug fixes first)

Comment: I'm using 2.2 as well. One quick question about the following line:

`$user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');`

I haven't inserted the registered users' `user_id` using the `set_userdata(); method. Do you think I should grab that column from the db and then pass it as a custom session data?

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty Consider using `Ion Auth` / `Tank Auth` for authentication, they handle sessions and everything for you, i suggest this because they have been tested/debugged/updated for years, and handle possible security issues, don't reinvent the wheel, anyway you can set session on login page after checking user's authentication (username/password) is correct, something like SELECT user_id, username WHERE username=xyz AND password=xyz , so you have the user_id etc and can set them in session, remember to check session on your controllers and redirect users to login if they have accessed re